# C# Socket Server - Issue with Concurrent Connections

Tags: c#, .net, flash, sockets

hey all, 
I have made a socket server in C# for a flash game that I am developing, I got the code from somewhere and I am a beginner in c# and .net development . It works fine in practice when connections are made and the server functions correctly. Get 2 concurrent connections at the same time and we have a problem.

here is the basic aspects of the socket server below: (alot taken out for obvious reasons)

how can I alter this so that it can handle concurrent connections? Should I be threading each response?

Thanks

`class TcpSock
    {
        int tcpIndx = 0;
        int tcpByte = 0;`

```
    byte[] tcpRecv = new byte[1024];

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    public Socket tcpSock;
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    public int Recv(ref string tcpRead)
    {
        tcpByte = tcpSock.Available;
        if (tcpByte > tcpRecv.Length - tcpIndx)
            tcpByte = tcpRecv.Length - tcpIndx;

        tcpByte = tcpSock.Receive(tcpRecv, tcpIndx, tcpByte,
            SocketFlags.Partial);
        tcpRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString
            (tcpRecv, tcpIndx, tcpByte);
        tcpIndx += tcpByte;
        return tcpRead.Length;
    }

    public int RecvLn(ref string tcpRead)
    {
        tcpRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString
            (tcpRecv, 0, tcpIndx);
        tcpIndx = 0;
        return tcpRead.Length;
    }

    public int Send(string tcpWrite)
    {
        return tcpSock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tcpWrite));
    }

    public int SendLn(string tcpWrite)
    {
        return tcpSock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tcpWrite + "\r\n"));
    }


}
```

`[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {`

```
        Thread Server1 = new Thread(RunServer);
        Server1.Start();

    }

    static void RunServer()
    {


        ///class IPHostEntry : Stores information about the Host and is required
        ///for IPEndPoint.
        ///class IPEndPoint  : Stores information about the Host IP Address and
        ///the Port number.
        ///class TcpSock     : Invokes the constructor and creates an instance.
        ///class ArrayList   : Stores a dynamic array of Client TcpSock objects.

        IPHostEntry Iphe = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPEndPoint Ipep = new IPEndPoint(Iphe.AddressList[0], 4444);
        Socket Server = new Socket(Ipep.Address.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        ///Initialize
        ///Capacity : Maximux number of clients able to connect.
        ///Blocking : Determines if the Server TcpSock will stop code execution
        ///to receive data from the Client TcpSock.
        ///Bind     : Binds the Server TcpSock to the Host IP Address and the Port Number.
        ///Listen   : Begin listening to the Port; it is now ready to accept connections.

        ArrayList Client = new ArrayList();

        string[,] Users = new string[1000,9];

        string rln = null;

        string[] Data;


        Client.Capacity = 1000;



        Server.Blocking = false;
        Server.Bind(Ipep);
        Server.Listen(32);

        Console.WriteLine("Server 1 {0}: listening to port {1}", Dns.GetHostName(), Ipep.Port);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///Main loop
        ///1. Poll the Server TcpSock; if true then accept the new connection.
        ///2. Poll the Client TcpSock; if true then receive data from Clients.

        while (true)
        {
            //Accept - new connection

            #region new connection
            if (Server.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                int i = Client.Add(new TcpSock());



                ((TcpSock)Client[i]).tcpSock = Server.Accept();
                Console.WriteLine("Client " + i + " connected.");


                Users[i, 0] = i.ToString();


            }
            #endregion 

            for (int i = 0; i < Client.Count; i++)
            {
                //check for incoming data
                if (((TcpSock)Client[i]).tcpSock.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                {
                    //receive incoming data
                    if (((TcpSock)Client[i]).Recv(ref rln) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(rln.ToString());
                        Data = rln.Split('|');

                        // 1) initial connection
                        #region InitialConnection

                        if (Data[0] == "0000")

                        {

                        }



                   }
               }
         }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
```

```
public static partial class TcpServer
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Setup listener on "localhost" port 12000
        IPAddress ipAddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddr, 12000);
        server.Start(); // Network driver can now allow incoming requests 

        // Accept up to 1 client per CPU simultaneously
        Int32 numConcurrentClients = Environment.ProcessorCount;

        for (Int32 n = 0; n 


    private static Byte[] ProcessData(Byte[] inputData)
    {
        String inputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputData, 1, inputData[0]);
        String outputString = inputString.ToUpperInvariant();

        Console.WriteLine("Input={0}", inputString);
        Console.WriteLine("   Output={0}", outputString);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Byte[] outputStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(outputString);
        Byte[] outputData = new Byte[1 + outputStringBytes.Length];
        outputData[0] = (Byte)outputStringBytes.Length;
        Array.Copy(outputStringBytes, 0, outputData, 1, outputStringBytes.Length);
        return outputData;
    }
}



public static partial class TcpServer
{
    private sealed class ClientConnectionApm
    {
        private TcpListener m_server;
        private TcpClient m_client;
        private Stream m_stream;
        private Byte[] m_inputData = new Byte[1];
        private Byte m_bytesReadSoFar = 0;



        public ClientConnectionApm(TcpListener server)
        {
            m_server = server;
            m_server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptCompleted, null);
        }



        private void AcceptCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Connect to this client
            m_client = m_server.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

            // Accept another client
            new ClientConnectionApm(m_server);

            // Start processing this client
            m_stream = m_client.GetStream();
            // Read 1 byte from client which contains length of additional data
            m_stream.BeginRead(m_inputData, 0, 1, ReadLengthCompleted, null);
        }



        private void ReadLengthCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // If client closed connection; abandon this client request
            if (m_stream.EndRead(result) == 0) { m_client.Close(); return; }

            // Start to read 'length' bytes of data from client
            Int32 dataLength = m_inputData[0];
            Array.Resize(ref m_inputData, 1 + dataLength);
            m_stream.BeginRead(m_inputData, 1, dataLength, ReadDataCompleted, null);
        }



        private void ReadDataCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Get number of bytes read from client
            Int32 numBytesReadThisTime = m_stream.EndRead(ar);

            // If client closed connection; abandon this client request
            if (numBytesReadThisTime == 0) { m_client.Close(); return; }

            // Continue to read bytes from client until all bytes are in
            m_bytesReadSoFar += (Byte)numBytesReadThisTime;
            if (m_bytesReadSoFar 


        private void WriteDataCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // After result is written to client, close the connection
            m_stream.EndWrite(ar);
            m_client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the older async approach which is a bit simpler than SocketEventArgs. It's borrowed from Jeffrey Richter. I recommend reading his book CLR via C#.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to not use synchronous functions but asynchrounus functions like Socket.BeginReceive

Answer (score -1):

First of all: Stop using non-blocking sockets. In .NET you should either stick to the synchronous methods `Receive`/`Send` or asynchronous methods `BeginReceive`/`BeginSend`.

You should only stick with sync methods if you will have only a handful of clients. Then launch each new client in a new thread. This is the easiest option to get everthing running.

Simply do like this:

```
public void AcceptClients()
{
     TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5566);
     listener.Start();

     while (_serverRunning)
     {
          var socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
          new Thread(ClientFunc).Start(socket);
     }
}

public void ClientFun(object state)
{
    var clientSocket = (Socket)state;
    var buffer = new byte[65535];
    while (_serverRunning)
    {
        //blocking read.
        clientSocket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        //check packet.

        // handle packet

        // send respons.
        clientSocket.Send(alalalal);
    }
}
```

You should refactor the methods so that they follow SRP. The code is just a small guide to get you going.

Comment: @Snoopy: Do you know how many clients a server need to have before one thread per connection becomes too slow to provide anything useful? Do you know how many clients the OP will have? I would NEVER recommend someone new to socket programming to start with asynchronous operations unless there are no other options. No premature optimizations please.

Comment: I had considered 1 thread per socket, but for around 1000 connections it would be too much!. I am a beginner, will be looking into all solutions suggested when I get in.. Thanks everyone, expect replies soon!

Comment: @jgauffin: the question says its for flash which means it's a web based solution. so we dont know how many connections we have. I wish i would have saved the time i wasted with sync sockets. But maybe it's a benefit from a beginner perspective to make the mistakes yourself for learning purposes...

Comment: So to ask my own question with the 2 replies. Should I use the above approach and concentrate on a single thread per user. Meaning a possible total of 1000 threads (this is going to be a flash mmorpg). or should I be using the Asynch methods of .net?

Comment: For 1000 clients you should use async methods.

Comment: the problems with 1000 clients is not only the threads which are forcing many context switches. you need alot of memory for the stack of each thread. not to mention if you want to debug production code, this will be a real nightmare :-)

Comment: Lets say for up to 20 concurrent connections sync sockets are ok. (for e.g. a prototype). But if you look at the TcpServer sample i posted above, you will notice async sockets is no magic :-) A way to make async programming alot simpler, look at this library, http://wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx 
this lets you write linear methods without distributing everything over many callback methods.

Comment: btw. there are client and server socket samples included.